# Non-differentiable at how many points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, continuity

There are two functions whose domain is $[-1/2,2]$ and whose co-domain is the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

They are $f(x) = \lfloor x^2-3\rfloor$,  where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, and $g(x) = |x|f(x) + |4x-7|f(x) $.

We have to find at how many points $g(x)$ is non-differentiable.

I tried but my answer is wrong . Why?

[image: dif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $g$ as
$$g(x):=\bigl(|x|+|4x-7|\bigr)\cdot\lfloor x^2-3\rfloor\ .$$
The first factor is continuous on $[-0.5,2]$, but not differentiable at $0$ and at ${7\over4}$. The second factor has 
 jump discontinuities at $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $2$, but is otherwise differentiable. We now have a "candidate list" consisting of six points. Looking at these points individually in turn we note that $\lfloor x^2-3\rfloor\equiv0$ for $\sqrt{3}\leq x<2$. This implies that ${7\over4}$ does no harm, so that we end up with the set $\bigl\{0,1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},2\}$ consisting of $5$ points.

Answer (score 2):

The function $|x| + |4x-7|$ has two edges, at $0$ and $7/4$, but $g(x)$ has only one at $0$, because it equals $0$ in and around $7/4$ ($7/4 > \sqrt 3$).

Comment: Why g(x) has only one edge ?

Comment: $g$ can only "inherit" edges from $|x|+|4x-7|$ (which are $0$ and $7/4$). But on interval $[\sqrt 3, 2)$ the function $f$ is $0$, so $g$ is constantly $0$ too, so no edges there. Also, $7/4 \in [\sqrt 3, 2)$.